# Show that this function is weakly differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I need to show that the function 
\begin{equation}
u(x_1,x_2) = 
1-x_1^2 \quad x_1>0
\\
u(x_1,x_2)=1+x_1^2 \quad x_1 \leq 0
\end{equation}
is weakly differentiable on the unit ball. It is clear what the weak derivative will be, but I am having a hard time showing that, when tested with a smooth function of compact support, the integration by parts does indeed work out as it should.

I have tried moving to polar coordinates to make the integration easier but I end up not being able to switch back into the regular coordinate system. This happens because when you do IBP you do not get $rdrd\theta$ just $drd\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your function as $u(x_1, x_2)=1-x_1\lvert x_1\rvert$. This makes evident that $u\in C^1$.

Comment: That is so much easier! Thanks